# event.preventDefault() not preventing form submit on jQuery Mobile .live() event

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to prevent a login form submittal so I can query a server, verify a username and password, and only then move on to the home page.

Here's the relevant code:

In login.html:

```
        <form id="login-form">
            <input type="text" name="login-username" id="login-username" value="" placeholder="Username" />
            <input type="password" name="login-password" id="login-password" value="" placeholder="Password" /><br />
            <button id="cab-submit" type="submit" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">Log In</button>
        </form>
```

In app.js:

```
    $("#login-form").live("submit", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.mobile.changePage("main.html", {
            transition: "fade"
        });
    });
```

I'm an experienced jQuery programmer but have never run into this. The changePage() does work but only happens after the form submits which causes an unnecessary page load.

**EDIT: Found the solution.**

I had to add data-ajax="false" to the form if I want to handle the form submittal myself. This worked fine.

New markup:

```
        <form id="login-form" data-ajax="false">
            <input type="text" name="login-username" id="login-username" value="" placeholder="Username" />
            <input type="password" name="login-password" id="login-password" value="" placeholder="Password" /><br />
            <button id="cab-submit" type="submit" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">Log In</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: What version of jQuery Mobile are you using?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Answered my own question. I had to add data-ajax="false" to the form if I want to handle the form submittal myself. This worked fine.

New markup:

```
    <form id="login-form" data-ajax="false">
        <input type="text" name="login-username" id="login-username" value="" placeholder="Username" />
        <input type="password" name="login-password" id="login-password" value="" placeholder="Password" /><br />
        <button id="cab-submit" type="submit" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">Log In</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this question, setting the event.preventDefault() within your event handler should be sufficient to prevent the form to submit, regardless of the form being ajax set or not; I'm using jquery mobile 1.3.1

Comment: Yes it should be. However it isn't for me, and I'm using 1.3.1 as well. Only after adding data-ajax="false" it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the id on the submit button to id="submit" and see what happens. It looks like it might be a known issue with jQuery mobile.